# How to Apply conditional CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Every thing is possible by CSS3, then how I do this by CSS?

(1)

```
<h2> Top Test Text </h2>
<h2> Test Text <span class="a"></span> </h2>
```

Apply `color: red` to only parent `h2` of `class="a"` not to top h2,
with out adding `<h2 style"color: red">` of with out adding class
There have any CSS Selectors to do that?
I Mean, Parent h2 will red color if `.a` class is present on the page.

(2)

```
<div class="a"> Test Text </div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Apply `color: red` to only `.a` if `.b` class is present on the page.

Comment: CSS cannot do this :(

Comment: once upon a time, the selector **:contains** was on W3C draft, you may find it in jQuery selectors/functions . selectors in css are conditionnal match BTW

Comment: How to do this By JS (1st one)

Comment: If you have different questions, please consider asking them separately.

Comment: @GCyrillus: That's `:has()` - `:contains()` is something completely different.

Comment: "*[Everything] is possible by CSS3*" - if only that initial premise was true.

Comment: @BoltClock  yes it is

Answer (score 0):

As commented: **CSS cannot do this**.

---

To answer at your comment:

In jQuery for the first example it would be:

```
$( "h2" ).has( "span.a" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

---

For both sub question , In jQuery you can use [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)  Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYGrBv